# We are running Winforms in Linux using Mono. We need to check an application is installed in Linux or not and launch if it is installed

Tags: c#, mono

We are developing a WinForm application which supports both windows and Linux(Using Mono). We want to check whether a particular application is installed or not and to launch if it is installed. In windows we are checking registry key( Using C#) and we can launch the same.how can we achieve this in Linux ? Do we need to write any shell scripting to access the installed registry location. I have little knowledge in Linux end. Need suggestion to resolve this , Any code snippet to use will be appreciable.

Comment: Linux doesnt have any registry. You must check whether process is running using "ps aux | grep someprocess" or you must find it inside some directories like "/etc/someprocess/*"...

Comment: Which application are you looking for? (There are not that many built for Windows and Linux).

Comment: @Jonathan Its a custom software we have installed in client machine we want run the instance in windows and Linux

Comment: How have you installed it? If you have written your own installation using c#, then Mono does provide an equivalent to the Windows registry, so you can store the installation path using your own key.  Standard registry commands work under mono.  In any case, the which command shown in my answer should work, as long as you installed it properly.

Answer (score 0):

To find an application, you can use the "which" command. You will need to use something like:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "which";
info.Arguments = "myapplication";

info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;

info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;

var p = Process.Start(info);

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Depending on what you need an external application for, the alternative is to rely on the file extension.  For example, if you write a report in excel format, you can get an application to open it simply by:

```
Process.Start("myfolder\myexcelbook.xlsx");
```

If the system has an application capable of opening the file, this will work.  This is the approach that I use in my application (also built for Windows and Unix/Linux), since the user is free to use different applications as he/she chooses, and not the one that I want (I provide output in xlsx, odt and pdf formats, and the above single line works for all of them).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan...I Will try this approach.

Comment: This really worked..Thanks a lot...and also i want to do the same thing in windows end ...i got few code samples where in one has to check registry key and sub key..is there any better approach ?

Comment: Glad to have helped!  For windows I would definitely use the Registry, assuming of course your installation actually writes to the Registry!  Most people use HKLM\Software\\[YourName].  Please mark this question as answered, and open a new question re Windows, if you want more info on finding applications in Windows (but check first for similar questions!)